# Should we add the other professional A/V related diciplines to the site?

Tags: discussion, scope

We currently cover Audio and Video, but this leaves out the somewhat closely related fields of Lighting and Stage Pyrotechnics.  The argument for pyrotechnics might be harder to make, but lighting is a key component of video production and is also a key component of any live production work, so it seems to make perfect sense as an expansion to the site's scope while staying true to the core purpose.  The site name Audio-Visual Production would fit this expanded scope with minimal other changes since the sub-domain would remain the same.

Comment: I took the liberty of rewriting your question as more of a proposal.  I hope you don't mind.  Personally, I like the idea.

Comment: Hmm, I noticed [this](http://meta.avp.stackexchange.com/questions/177/are-lighting-questions-on-topic/181#181) related post.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are on the right track that we **can do a *lot* better** at meeting the needs of our video community. Expanding and clarifying the scope through such changes is a good start. But coincidentally, we are working out some more comprehensive changes to help focus both the audio and the video community to help them *both* thrive.

Not to get too vague and stealthy, but I have a few more details to work out before going into any further details in the upcoming week(s). I just wanted to give you a heads up here to let you we are working on the same basic track.

Carry on.

Comment: Ohhhhh, how mysterious...!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at these posts to give you some insight into the thought process of defining the scope of the site as it is now.

[Proposal to add video to this site](https://video.meta.stackexchange.com/q/115/2569)

https://video.meta.stackexchange.com/q/165/2569

[Are non-production video and audio questions on topic here?](https://video.meta.stackexchange.com/q/204/2569)

Comment: Well I am talking about lighting and sound tech such as a question like "How do I set a cue on the ETC Express Boot?" Questions for Techies who do live visuals and sound

Comment: Also, check out [this question](http://meta.avp.stackexchange.com/q/298/2569) and it's answers.  In the end, I don't think the question of stage production has been definitively answered, though most answers lean towards *no*.  You could always post your question... the community will likely let you know whether or not it is on topic for the site.  If it's an edge case, it could go either way.

Comment: I do Audio Video production and stage production. I also think this site should have a better name.

Answer (score 0):

I had honestly never even thought about the fact that it doesn't include lighting, but it does seem like it would make sense to add that to the scope of the site along with pyrotechnics.  If the site was doing better, I'd say it should be it's own area, but it does seem like that additional expansion could potentially bring in further users and we do have at least one experienced lighting tech that is already an active member of the site.

I don't know pyrotechnics yet though, but I'd love to learn more about it if we could attract anyone that does know that area.

Answer (score 0):

Now that Video is a site of its own, you've got some additional latitude to expand and tweak your scope. Robert doesn't kid around when he says there's something planned :)

Just raise new ideas here on meta if you think that they require a community discussion, something in the form of:

> Should our scope also include [topic?]

I'm certain that if it would be of interest to people in video production, and not likely to create new problems, it'll probably be fine.

Comment: I would suggest that a liberal interpretation of video production already includes a lot of the other areas. Lighting, audio, effects, cg, etc are all part of video production. Even things about actors and business related to managing a video production are arguably on topic since they all relate directly to video production.